# Assign a list created into a java method to a list passed as parameter

Tags: java

I am doing some experiments with java list. I have pass a list parameter to a simple method which add two strings into a new list. At the final I have assigned to the parameter list the list created in the method.

I have expected to have the following result:

`[a, b]` but I'm getting `[c, d]`

I have this code:

```
public class A {

public static void f(List<String> list){
    List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();

    list2.add("a");
    list2.add("b");

    list = list2;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    list.add("c");
    list.add("d");

    f(list);
    System.out.println(list);
  }
}
```

Can anyone explain me what is happening in the background ?

Comment: You meant `c,d`?

Comment: Yes. I am wrong

Comment: FYI - the code you posted never calls the method you wrote. Your code makes a list, adds 2 items to it, then prints it.

Comment: I have updated in the main

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java assign method parameters 'by value' (in opposed to 'by reference' and 'by pointer').

When you call

```
void f(List<String> list)
```

You pass a pointer to a list. The pointer to the list is **copied** to another variable and the assignment

```
list = list2
```

assign 'list2' to a separate copy of the pointer. Means that by this assignment the original pointer remains unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

You have not called f(list) in your main()
and even if you call it, then also you will get [c,d]
as you are not changing the passed list.
you are just changing the local list reference in f()

Answer (score 0):

In your main function :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    list.add("c");
    list.add("d");

    System.out.println(list);
}
```

You have created a list and added two elements to that list. And than you have simply printed that list, that is why you are always getting [c,d] as output. You have never called your function f().

Now in your function f() :

```
public static void f(List<String> list){
    List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();

    list2.add("a");
    list2.add("b");

    list = list2;
}
```

It expects a reference to a list as parameter.

step 1: `List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();` creates a new list.

Than you add two elements to this new list.

And then in step `list = list2;` you are simply changing the reference of the list and now it points to list2. But you are no where manipulating the list created in the main method. So even if you call the function `f(list)` from  main method, no changes will be reflected to your list in main method.